# Tailwind UI Transition Component + React Spectrum Overlay Not Working

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

**Sandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-brook-de970

**Packages:** [React Spectrum](https://react-spectrum.adobe.com/react-aria/useOverlayTrigger.html), [Tailwind Transition Component](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindui-react)

**The Problem:** The `useOverlayPosition` users two refs, a `triggerRef` and an `overlayRef` to determine the absolute positioning that should be applied to the popup.

Without transitions, there are no issues with positioning.

When I add the [Transition component](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindui-react), I notice that the `overlayRef` isn't set once rendered and therefore doesn't allow the `useOverlayPosition` hook to determine the right positioning props to apply.  I assume this is because the `state.isOpen` is false and the children of the `Transition` component aren't rendered yet.

A subsequent press while open fixes the issue.

1. Clicking off the button continues the issue.
2. Clicking on the button after it's open will fix the issue, but I don't understand why.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved using a callbackRef instead of `useRef`.  This allowed the component to re-render when the ref was assigned.

In a `useRef`, updating `ref.current` does not trigger a re-render but with a `callbackRef` it will.

Idea taken from: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-can-i-measure-a-dom-node

```
const [overlayRef, setOverlayRef] = React.useState<
    React.RefObject<HTMLElement>
  >({ current: null });

  const callbackRef = React.useCallback((node) => {
    if (node !== null) {
      setOverlayRef({ current: node });
    }
  }, []);
```